# ListView Child Item Selection triggers the Parent control Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In My WPF User control  the control hierarchy in Xaml is shown below

Tab Control
 ------ Tab Item
------------- ListView
------------------------ListViewItem

**List View item template is made of stack panel and few text blocks.**

I am able to get the selected list view item .
but on selection of the listview item the Tab item selection is also triggered .
How should i avoid this.?? 
How can i prevent the ListView item selection propagating to its parent controls?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

by Handled property of RoutedEventArgs.

In selection -event handler of child listview.

```
private void selection_handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ((RoutedEventArgs)(e)).Handled = true;
}
```

After do that, selection is not propagated to event handler of parent control.

Comment: For list view i could not find a selected event :(